# How to mock DB2 XML Scalar Functions in HSQLDB

Tags: sql, unit-testing, db2, hsqldb

I need to test DB2 query with XML scalar functions using HSQLDB.
I am using HSQLDB in DB2 mode but still getting the exception 
`org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: XMLSERIALIZE`.

Could somebody help with that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: HSQLDB simply doesn't support this. Another good reason why using different DBMS for unit testing and production doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Yeah, seems like there is no way to test my queries. Thanks for the answer!